# How to resume the CAAnimation group after cell reuse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caanimation

I wrote some CAAnimation code in Cell. It's working proper at the first show of cell. but after the cell reuse. The animations is stop. Almost all the way on internet. It remove the animation and add again. But I hope I can get the animation and resume again. Anyone know how to that? Thanks for your help.

I also find apple give a way to stop and resume the CAAnimation. But It's seem don't work in my project only use the resume code.
Here is the line. [QA1673](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1673/_index.html)

I use CAAnimationDelegate to watch the animation status. When the cell scrolled out of bounds, They call the `- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag` to tell the animation is stop. so apple stop it not by accident.

That's the all info I got.

Comment: Where do you put your animation? Maybe you should put it in the `willDisplayCell` function.

Comment: - (void)awakeFromNib. but I set the CAAnimation to repeat forever.

Comment: What about creating the CAAnimation object in `awakeFromNib` but adding it to the layer in `prepareForReuse`?

Comment: if you add it at prepareForReuse. The cell will don't have any animation at the first time. prepareForReuse only call it when the cell use again.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, the cell's `awakeFromNib` is only called once for a cell, even though it potentially will be reused many times. I would suggest to put your code as follows:

**In `UITableViewCell` or sub-class**

`- (void)awakeFromNib`
 
Called once for the lifetime of the cell.
Place initialization code that is *independent* of the cell's content.

`- (void)prepareForReuse`
Called when the cell is about to be re-cycled.
Place cleanup code that must be called before reusing the cell here. Usually you do not need to use this, but can put the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead. See below.

**In class implementing `UITableViewDataSource`**

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
 
Called for every cell the table view wants to display.
Place initialization code that is *dependent* of the cell's content here. I suggest you put your animation code here.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I don't want to show the animation view to view controller. I also think it not right to put the animation code in controller.  Now I add the animation code in '- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier' function. when the cell is reused. I use the key to check the animation is exists. if already had it. remove and add it again. It's working maybe not a intelligent way.

Comment: @Huanrong You can keep your animation specific code in the cell class if you want, just put it in a function that you call from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: But I think you will add too much CAAnimation to one cell, after you use the cell for a while. we set the animation repeat forever, they will not remove automatic.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I see the difference. If you add a `configureAnimation` function to your cell class, then that function can check if an animation is already present, remove it if so, then finally add it. This would have the same result as your current solution, but with the benefit to keep the animation specific code in one function in your cell class. Of course, your current solution works too.

Comment: Okay.The way I used don't need let the controller to know what time to start the animation. But Where to put the animation code is not my question. Actually I want to know what happing after cell reuse. why the animation is stop and whether have a way to let it start again. I don't want remove and add it again before reuse.